# Remove Order from datamember

Tags: wcf, datacontract, datamember

Is there anything which can be use to avoid using Order attribute in DataMember while passing parameters from xml to WCF service

```
[DataMember(Name = "Name", Order = 2)]
...
[DataMember(Name = "ID", Order = 1)]
...
```

Comment: then values are coming as null for few parameters.. I want it to be independent of any order

Answer (score 2):

No there is no way of avoiding using the Order DataMemberAttribute if you are passing members in an order which differs from those that the serializer are expecting.

The rules for ordering are outlined here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729813.aspx

> The basic rules for data ordering include:
>
> - If a data contract type is a part of an inheritance hierarchy, data members of its base types are always first in the order.
> - Next in order are the current type’s data members that do not have the Order property of the DataMemberAttribute attribute set, in
>     alphabetical order.
> - Next are any data members that have the Order property of the DataMemberAttribute attribute set. These are ordered by the value of
>     the Order property first and then alphabetically if there is more than
>     one member of a certain Order value. Order values may be skipped.

If you pass members which do not conform to these rules then you will get null values as the serializer will skip them. I know it's not great but this is unfortunately the way it works.